# The meaning of RET 2 in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am very new to assembly, and I don't understand what it exactly means when, at the end of a proc, you write a number with the `ret` statement.

Like this:

```
Function Proc
push ax cx
.
...body...
.
pop cx ax
ret 2 
Function endp
```

I understand it has something to do with where the stack pointer should return to at the end of the function?

What does it do?

Comment: Assembly isn't one language - every processor has its own. You should ask about a specific architecture (x86, it seems).

Comment: Off-topic: `ret` is a powerful little instruction that has long been the centre of exploiting buggy software: It directs the program's control flow according to the content of the memory of the call stack. If you control the memory (`strcpy`, I'm looking at you), you control the program execution flow.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, but `ret 2` also removes 2 bytes of parameters from the stack. Presumably, your function was called like:

```
push some_parameter
call Function
```

At this point, a `cdecl` function - a "caller cleans up" function (Generally used by C) - would require `add sp, 2` to "clean up the stack", removing the parameter. Such a function would end in a plain `ret`.

A `stdcall` function, which is what you've got, is a "callee cleans up" function (used by Windows APIs, for example) doesn't require the `add sp, 2` - it has been done by the `ret 2`.

If you're not aware of it, `call` puts the return address on the stack (and `ret` pops it off), so you can't just `pop` to get the parameter inside your function.

Comment: Intel's manual entry for `ret` has details: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret

Answer (score 25):

Lets say I have a procedure to add two words and leave the sum in `EAX`. The words are arguments I want to pass to the procedure on the stack. i.e:

```
push word1
push word2
call addtwob
```

The procedure would look something like:

```
addtwob proc

push ebp
mov  ebp,esp
mov  eax, [ebp+6]    
add  eax, [ebp+8]
pop ebp
ret 4

Endp
```

`[ebp+6]` and `[ebp+8]` address `word2` and `word1` on the stack.
`ret 4` just returns like usual but then adds 4 to the stack pointer (`esp`) so you don't have to `pop word2` `pop word1` off the stack after returning from the call, therefore it cleans/balances the stack without needing to pop the previous pushes.

Comment: So pop clears ebp that was set, ret clears the return address and setting '4' after ret clears an additional 4 bytes i.e. the two words. Is this correct?

Comment: 32-bit code (using EBP and ESP) would normally use DWORD (4-byte) stack slots for its args.  Also, the original call would push a 4-byte return address.  So `mov eax, [ebp+8]` / `add eax, [ebp+12]`.

Answer (score 10):

As alex said, it means RETURN.
In x86 assembly, when the compiler reaches to this line (at the end of a subroutine, for example), it pops the **last** value from the stack, which supposed to be the returning address, and assigned it to IP register. You can understand that better by writing a simple assembler code and compile it with Turbo Debugger. There's a GUI for assembler if you are new to that. You can find the GUI [here](http://c0ldsh3ll.com/ta-gui.html).

When you are poping and pushing values from and to the stack when you are in a subroutine, you should store the returning address, because in the end of the subrouting you need to push it back in to the stack before the `return` line.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

It means RETurn, like a `return` in high level languages.

On most machines, it will pop the program counter's previous value before entering the subroutine off of the stack and copy it to the PC's register.

For x86, the argument is the number of parameters on the stack. This applies only if the convention used is to have the subroutine handle the resetting the stack.

Comment: so what is the meaning of the number next to it?

Comment: Minor correction: the immediate operand specifies the number of extra _bytes_ to "pop" off the stack when returning.

Comment: @Michael Thanks, that was what I was implying but it may not have been obvious.

Answer (score 3):

for x86 32 bit "The optional numeric (16- or 32-bit) parameter to ret specifies the number of stack bytes or words to be released after the return address is popped from the stack. Typically, these bytes or words are used as input parameters to the called procedure.  "-- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3773/instructionset-67/index.html

so first it pops the return address then the optional number refers to the number of BYTES to increment the stack after popping the return address.

`ret 4` would be a total of `esp+=8` in 32-bit mode, including popping the 4-byte return address and 4 bytes that the caller had pushed.

Comment: removing bytes from the stack increments ESP, not dec.  So `ret N` is like a normal ret and then `add esp, N` (but without modifying FLAGS).

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking about a **near return with an operand for x86_64**. Algorithm that is followed by the hardware when near RET is encountered by the processor is shown in [Intel instruction set reference manual](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325383.pdf) is as follows;

```
(* Near return *)
IF instruction = near return
    THEN;
    IF OperandSize = 32
        THEN
        IF top 4 bytes of stack not within stack limits
            THEN #SS(0); FI; //throw protected mode exception
        EIP ← Pop(); 
        ELSE
        IF OperandSize = 64
            THEN
            IF top 8 bytes of stack not within stack limits
                THEN #SS(0); FI; //throw protected mode exception
            RIP ← Pop();
            ELSE (* OperandSize = 16 *)
            IF top 2 bytes of stack not within stack limits
                THEN #SS(0); FI; //throw protected mode exception
            tempEIP ← Pop();
            tempEIP ← tempEIP AND 0000FFFFH;
            IF tempEIP not within code segment limits
                THEN #GP(0); FI; //throw protected mode exception
            EIP ← tempEIP;
        FI;
    FI;
    IF instruction has immediate operand
        THEN (* Release parameters from stack *)
        IF StackAddressSize = 32
            THEN
            ESP ← ESP + SRC;
            ELSE
            IF StackAddressSize = 64
                THEN
                RSP ← RSP + SRC;
                ELSE (* StackAddressSize = 16 *)
            SP ← SP + SRC;
            FI;
        FI;
    FI;
FI;
```

- According to this algorithm whenever a near return is encountered, return address is checked whether it is in SS limits. The top of the stack is popped in to RIP or EIP according to the operand size if the return address is valid.
- If the operand size is 16 bits a temporary location holds popped return address that is ANDed with the value 0x0000FFFF and is loaded into the EIP after checking CS limits.
- As your question asks about what happens if there is an operand to the near RET instruction opcode. It depends on the stack address size. According to that size RSP ESP or SP is increased by operand and after all the near RET instruction is completed execution on the hardware.

Comment: `pop cx` is a pretty clear sign that the OP was looking at 16-bit code.  For some reason people ask a lot of Stack Overflow questions about 16-bit code.  Some of them are making toy OSes, most of them are taking university courses that teach 8086 with emu8086 for some insane reason.